# JavaScript "document is not defined" error when script is not a part of the page

Tags: javascript, regex, social-networking

**What I want to do:** I want to get message from the web page with posts.
Then I'd like to parse the message into strings according to regular expressions rules.
(For example, find all the sentences containing a word "bug").

I've chosen JavaScript for no reason - so if there's better way of doing it - please be so kind to mention it.

**What I do:** I open [URL](http://vk.com/topic-59389006_28908655?offset=180), then I launch JavaScript, which should

```
var x=document.getElementById("post-59389006_839");
alert (x.value);
//or
var x=document.getElementById("bp_data-59389006_839").innerHTML;
alert(x);
```

...but it shows "ReferenceError: document is not defined" error.
If I download the page, then insert my script into it, of course, it works.

**Questions**:

> 1. What am I doing wrong with my JavaScript?
> 2. Is there a better way to parse the strings from web-pages using regexp?

p.s. *Usually I can find the answers to all my questions (someone has already asked and answered them), but now I either completely misuse JS, or I failed in googling.*

Comment: You open a url in what? Some webdriver? or Browser? Are you trying to get posts from your own webpage via JS?

Comment: how do you launch javascript ? I thought Brendan Eich did that years ago :)

Comment: @Tamil, I open URL in a browser. The page is not mine (although I can insert JS code to a locally saved page, I would rather not do it. I'd like to get posts from the page without some "elevated" rights, e.g. being the creator of a site).

Comment: @AmitJoki, I use iMacro, although, I don't think that this is worth mentioning - I tried double-clicking it, launching it via Firefox.

Comment: If you wish to execute javascript in a scrapped page, read on Phantomjs or jsdom. I'm still not getting what are u trying to do.. `I can insert JS code to a locally saved page `You mean view source and take the content?

Comment: @Tamil, yes. I can save the html page locally and add

Comment: ...add my code to the HEAD part of the source code:

`<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {
    var x=document.getElementById("post-59389006_839");
    alert (x.value);
    }
    </script>`
Then call that function from BODY part of the code, inserting:
`<button onclick="myFunction()">Boom!</button>`
What I'm trying to do is to execute JS functions from my own page/script so, that those functions could collect the data from another page (e.g. posts from Facebook).

Answer (score 0):

1. The script is being loaded and run *before* the page loads. This means that the element that you are attempting to read from has not actually been loaded, and thus returns an error when the script attempts  to read from it. In fact, the document node has not even been loaded yet, which is what produces `ReferenceError: document is not defined`.

   There are two ways to avoid this: either insert the `<script></script>` tags at the bottom of the HTML for the page (which does not appear to be feasible, as you do not have access to the server), or set your function to be called upon the document loading (search for 'js event listeners').
2. RegExp is probably your best bet.

On a side note, JS is the only way that you are likely to be able to dynamically edit pages after they have been loaded. Perhaps try GreaseMonkey or TamperMonkey as opposed to iMacro, however.